# Passing a filename with an apostrophe into scp using python

Tags: python, bash, scp

I'm trying to write a python script to copy files from a remote server to a local directory via scp.

Because I'm running this on an OpenELEC distribution (minimal HTPC linux distro, read-only filesystem except for userhome makes it impractical to install python ssh module), I'm doing this ugly and just passing the filename to the scp command via os.system.

```
SCPCopy = "scp -c blowfish -C user@host:\"" + pipes.quote(file) + "\" /storage/downloads/incoming/"
SCPCopy = SCPCopy.replace('\n','')
os.system(SCPCopy)
```

This works, except for filenames containing an apostrophe.

Below is an example of what gets passed to os.system in a file with an apostrophe:

```
scp -c blowfish -C user@host:"'/media/sdi1/home/data/bob'"'"'s file.avi'" /storage/downloads/incoming/
```

And the error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

It looks pipes.quote(x) is escaping the apostrophe (as it should), but obviously the syntax is still incorrect. I've experimented ditching pipes.quote(x) and replacing apostrophes with /' but that isn't getting me anywhere either.

Comment: Python docs say that `pipes.quote` is deprecated since version 1.6!

Comment: I've tried not using pipes.quote and just replacing apostrophes like so: SCPCopy = SCPCopy.replace("'", "\'")

However, I get the same error.

Comment: Use `shlex.quote` and do NOT use your own `\"`.

Comment: or you could rename your file not to have an apostrophe. Good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `scp` is based on `SSH`, the filenames you give to it are subject to shell escaping on the remote side as well. Thus you need to escape twice.

A correctly escaped cmdline for the shell:

```
scp -c blowfish -C user@host:"\"/media/sdi1/home/data/bob's file\"" /storage/.../
```

To make a python string, we have to add one more level of escaping. To stay sane, we could use triple-quotes:

```
"""scp -c blowfish -C user@host:"\"/media/sdi1/home/data/bob's file\"" /storage/.../"""
```

If you do it programmatically (e.g. using the deprecated `pipes.quote`), then don't touch the filename at all (in your example above, you added apostrophes around the filename).

```
fp = "/media/sdi1/home/data/bob's file.avi"
fp = "user@host:" + pipes.quote(pipes.quote(fp))

cmdline = "scp -c blowfish -C " + fp + " /storage/downloads/incoming/"
os.system(cmdline)
```

This is admittedly confusing. For a simple model, the whole point of `pipes.quote` is to escape the input so that the input will be parsed by the shell as exactly **one word**, which is **equal to the input**.

The following is a more generally correct way (and yields the same result):

```
fp = "/media/sdi1/home/data/bob's file.avi"
# the filepath argument escaped for ssh/scp on the remote side
fp = pipes.quote(fp)
commandargs = ["scp", "-c", "blowfish", "-C", "user@host:"+fp, "/storage/downloads/incoming/"]
# escape all words for the local shell, and then concatenate space-separated
cmdline = " ".join(map(pipes.quote, commandargs))
os.system(cmdline)
```

It expresses more clearly the intent: Controlling what words exactly the shell will parse.

But why start with a shell in the first place? We don't need one and can save the escaping on the local side. To spawn a process with our args, directly, use commands from the `os.exec*` family.

```
fp = pipes.quote("/media/sdi1/home/data/bob's file.avi")
commandargs = ["scp", "-c", "blowfish", "-C", "user@host:"+fp, "/storage/downloads/incoming/"]
if os.fork() == 0:
    os.execvp("scp", commandargs)
```

Comment: Great, thank you - that worked.
I did have to move the user@host over to the cmdline string as pipes.quote was adding an apostrophe to the username.
EDIT: Just noticed your updates - very informative, thank you!