# Using shlex to split commands with spaces and apostrophe

Tags: python

I have a problem with my python script. I want to download files from my server to my NAS. My script is downloading every file, except for files containing single quotes/apastrophes and/or spaces. I already know where the problem is, but I can't fix it. The problem is with the `shlex.split()` command. It just deletes the single quotes. I also looked into paramiko, but it's kinda buggy with big files, so that won't work for me. I am also open for a completly different approach.

I was also wondering if it is possible to get a return for that command, so that I know that scp succesfully downloaded my file or if it failed.

```
import subprocess
import shlex    
def download(download_path, remote_path):
    command = "sshpass -p %s scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r %s@%s:%s %s"  %\
              (ssh_password, ssh_user, host, remote_path, download_path)
    args = shlex.split(command)
    # call scp
    p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line,
    p.stdout.close()
    p.wait()
```

P.S.: There already is a topic with a similar problem, which I can't get working. [Passing a filename with an apostrophe into scp using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784454/passing-a-filename-with-an-apostrophe-into-scp-using-python)

Comment: Try `shlex.split(command, posix=False)`

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the fast reply. I gave it a shot and got a new error:

`bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''` \
`bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting an arbitrary string that needs to be split; you are basically starting out with the individual words and concatenating them yourself. Don't do that; just make `command` a list to begin with.

```
command = [
    "sshpass", "-p", ssh_password,
    "scp", "-o", "StrictHostKeyChecking=no", "-r",
    "%s@%s:%s" % (ssh_user, host, remote_path),
    download_path
]

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1)
```